# Nginx и своя страница ошибки

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, ispmanager, fastcgi

Есть сервер с ISPmanager Lite 5.208.0. На нём сайт, у которого нужно сменить страницу 404 на свою.

Внесли следующие настройки:

```
error_page 404 /404.php;
location  /404.php {
   internal;
}
```

Результат нулевой - выдаёт стандартную страницу. Хотя сама страница доступна по ссылке /404.php

P.S. PHP работает в режиме FastCGI (Nginx + PHP-FPM)

Comment: Роулинг внутри приложения происходит?...

Comment: Это что? Можно поподробнее?

Comment: Добавить `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;` и прочую обвязку вызова пыха

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uqaLs9i1 - вот весь конфиг домена.

Comment: Роутинг - опечатался